# No se inserta ni modifica los datos de la tabla de Mysql con Java

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, java-swing

nose porque no se me inserta los valores al Phpmyadmin, ya tengo instalado lo que se necesita pra conectarlo y cuando lo conecto si lo hace, pero en el tema de los valores me da de que no guardo, aun no se porque no inserta al php. En si estoy utilizando Xampp con Phpmyadmin que tiene mysql.

En si posiblemente sea como puse el insert, aunque ya lo habia provado con varias formas y aun me da error. Talvez sea la obtencion de los datos pero no lo se p-p

y bueno :u la pagina aun no me deja ponerlo,porque dice que de mas detalles de lo que ya no puedo dar mas porque eso es todo?.

-Parte 1

```
package Registro;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Sql_Registr{
private String BasedeDatos ="registro";
private String Usuario ="root";
private String Password ="";
private String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+BasedeDatos;

static Connection conectar = null;

public Sql_Registr(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        conectar =DriverManager.getConnection(url,Usuario,Password);
        
        if(conectar != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conexion hecha con "+BasedeDatos);
        }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error" + e.getMessage());
    }catch(SQLException es) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error" + es.getMessage());
    }
}
public static Connection getConnection() {
    return conectar;
}
public void Desconectar() {
    conectar = null;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws SQLException{
    Sql_Registr a = new Sql_Registr();
    
    if (Sql_Registr.conectar != null) {
        System.out.println("Correcto");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no");
      }
    } 
  }
```

-Parte 2

```
package Registro;

public class Registro {

private int id;
private String Nombres;
private String Apellidos;
private String nacionaldiad;
private String Fecha_nac;
private String genero;


public Registro () {
}


public Registro(int id, String nombres, String apellidos, String nacionaldiad, String fecha_nac, String genero) {
    this.id = id;
    this.Nombres = nombres;
    this.Apellidos = apellidos;
    this.nacionaldiad = nacionaldiad;
    this.Fecha_nac = fecha_nac;
    this.genero = genero;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getNombres() {
    return Nombres;
}


public void setNombres(String nombres) {
    Nombres = nombres;
}


public String getApellidos() {
    return Apellidos;
}


public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    Apellidos = apellidos;
}


public String getNacionaldiad() {
    return nacionaldiad;
}


public void setNacionaldiad(String nacionaldiad) {
    this.nacionaldiad = nacionaldiad;
}


public String getFecha_nac() {
    return Fecha_nac;
}


public void setFecha_nac(String fecha_nac) {
    Fecha_nac = fecha_nac;
}


public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}


public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Registro [id="+ id +", Nombres="+ Nombres +", Apellidos="+ Apellidos +", nacionaldiad="+ nacionaldiad +", Fecha_nac="+ Fecha_nac +", genero="+ genero +"]";
 }
}
```

--parte 3

```
package Registro;

import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.sql.*;

public class EmpleadoDAO {

private String Mensaje;

public String AgreagarEmpleado(Connection conectar, Registro empleado) {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO `empleados`(`id`, `Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Nacionalidad`, `Fecha_Nacimiento`, `Sexo`)"
            + " VALUES ('[?]','[?]','[?]','[?]','[?]','[?]')";
    
    try {
        pst = conectar.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, empleado.getId());
        pst.setString(2, empleado.getNombres());
        pst.setString(3, empleado.getApellidos());
        pst.setString(4, empleado.getNacionaldiad());
        pst.setString(5, empleado.getFecha_nac());
        pst.setString(6, empleado.getGenero());
        Mensaje = "guardado";
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = "No guardado";
        
    }
    
    return Mensaje;
}
public String EliminarEmpleado(Connection conectar, int id) {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql = "Delete from empleado where id = ?";
    
    try {
        pst = conectar.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        Mensaje = "guardado";
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = "No guardado";
        
    }
    
    return Mensaje;
}
public String ModificarEmpleado(Connection conectar, Registro empleado) {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql = "Update empleado Set Nombres = ?, Apellidos = ?, Nacionalidad = ?, Fecha_Nacimiento = ?, Sexo = ?" +
    "Where id = ?";
    
    try {
        pst = conectar.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, empleado.getNombres());
        pst.setString(2, empleado.getApellidos());
        pst.setString(3, empleado.getNacionaldiad());
        pst.setString(4, empleado.getFecha_nac());
        pst.setString(5, empleado.getGenero());
        pst.setInt(6, empleado.getId());
        Mensaje = "guardado";
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = "No guardado";
        
    }
    return Mensaje;
}
public String LimpiarTabla(Connection conectar, JTable tabla) {
    return Mensaje;
}
}
```

--Parte 4

```
package Registro;

import java.sql.Connection;

import Registro.EmpleadoDAO;

public class EmpleadoBO {
private String Mensaje = "";
private EmpleadoDAO edao= new EmpleadoDAO();

public String AgreagarEmpleado(Registro empleado){
    Connection conexion = Sql_Registr.getConnection();
    try {
        Mensaje = edao.AgreagarEmpleado(conexion, empleado);
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage(); 
    }finally {
        try {
            if(conexion != null) {
                conexion.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return Mensaje;
}
public String ModificarEmpleado(Registro empleado){
    Connection conexion = Sql_Registr.getConnection();
    try {
        Mensaje = edao.ModificarEmpleado(conexion, empleado);           
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage(); 
    }finally {
        try {
            if(conexion != null) {
                conexion.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return Mensaje; }
public String EliminarEmpleado(int id){
    Connection conexion = Sql_Registr.getConnection();
    try {
        Mensaje = edao.EliminarEmpleado(conexion, id);
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage(); 
    }finally {
        try {
            if(conexion != null) {
                conexion.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Mensaje = Mensaje + " " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return Mensaje;
}
public String LimpiarTabla() {
    return Mensaje;
}
}
```

--Parte prueba

```
package Registro;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import Registro.*;

public class test {

EmpleadoBO EBO= new EmpleadoBO();
Registro emp = new Registro();
String Mensaje = "";


public void insertar(){
    emp.setNombres("sas");
    emp.setApellidos("asa");
    emp.setFecha_nac("0");
    emp.setId(2);
    emp.setNacionaldiad("sas");
    emp.setGenero("sas");
    Mensaje = EBO.AgreagarEmpleado(emp);
    System.out.println(Mensaje);
    
}
public void modificar(){
    emp.setId(1);
    emp.setNombres("sas");
    emp.setApellidos("asa");
    emp.setFecha_nac("2020/04/04");
    emp.setNacionaldiad("sas");
    emp.setGenero("sas");
    Mensaje = EBO.ModificarEmpleado(emp);
    System.out.println(Mensaje);
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    test test = new test();
    test.insertar();
}

}
```

Comment: Conviene que siempre agregues a la pregunta el o los mensajes de error. La parte de `VALUES` en el INSERT, está mal escrita, debes ponerla así: **`VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";`** Es decir, solamente un marcador `?` por cada columna, sin comillas ni más cosas.